# How to use the completion handler in dismissViewControllerAnimated with Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

While refactoring an app from Objective-C to Swift I ran into a problem, which I cannot resolve on my own.

`ViewControllerOne` has the method
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`. In this method I am setting the `destinationViewController`:
`ViewControllerTwo *viewControllerTwo = [segue destinationViewController];`
and some block handler like this:

```
[viewControllerTwo setHandlerOne:^(id sender) {
    [...]
}]
```

Then while touching on a button I am showing a modal view.
In the modal view controller `ViewControllerTwo` I am closing this modal view:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.handlerOne(sender);
}
```

In the Swift code I have set up the same:
`ViewControllerOne` with method:
`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`
Set the `destinationViewController`
`let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerTwo`
And the code block:

```
vc.setHandlerOne { () -> Void in
    [...]
}
```

This way I get the error `Value of type 'ViewControllerTwo' has no member 'setHandlerOne'`. What am I missing here? Do I have to manually set it in the `viewControllerTwo`?

Comment: are you sure your destinationViewController is a ViewControllerTwo object?

Comment: Post your swift code that is giving you the error

Comment: Wrong code. The problem is with your Swift code. Show your Swift code. Not your Objective-C code. No one cares about the Objective-C code. It's not causing the error, is it?

Comment: @matt Updated my question. Sorry. I thought I pasted my Swift code. Can you have another look at it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think your destinationViewController is not ViewControllerTwo type or may be possible if your destinationViewController is ViewControllerTwo type then ViewControllerTwo not contain setHandlerOne method.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. As you can see the `destinationViewController` is a `viewControllerTwo`. And my `viewControllerTwo` has a property `handlerOne`. And this property I try to set in `prepareForSegue` in `viewControllerOne`.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can do what you are described as:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {  
    if let viewControllerTwo: ViewControllerTwo = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerTwo{
        viewControllerTwo.setHandler({ (sender) in

        })
    }
}
```

and in the `ViewControllerTwo` define the method:

```
func setHandler(completion:((AnyObject?) -> Void)?){

}
```

I posted the version with the completion block...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to define the setter of the property `handlerOne` in the `prepareForSegue` method, not just calling a method from `viewControllerTwo`. Please have a look at the Objective-C example.

Comment: The method should always defined inside the view controller, you talk about the completion handler?